# ng-click not working on a programmatically added buttons

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm trying to add some buttons (`ons-button`) dynamically. The buttons appear as expected but the `ng-click` related to them never gets fired. It seems to be a problem with my understanding of how DOM manipulation works under AngularJS.

I have tried to read related questions, but most of them are trying to use directives, so I would like to use the simple way here.

Here is the code:

```
    var module = angular.module("my-app", ["onsen"]);

    module.controller("ListenButtonController", [
      "$http",
      "$scope",
      function($http, $scope) {
      var myList = [];
        $scope.onButtonClick = function(message){
          alert('Button clicked, with the message '+message);
        }

        $scope.onAddButtons = function(newList){
          myList = [...newList];
        }

        }


      }
      ]);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="ListenButtonController">
      <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="onAddButtons(['a','b','c'])">
        Click to test
    </ons-button>
    <ons-button ng-repeat="element in myList" ng-click="onButtonClick(element)"></ons-button>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Just wondering, why are you adding the buttons programmatically instead of using something like `ng-if` or `ng-show`?

Comment: Use `ng-repeat` to create the buttons, don't add them by `forEach` and `.innerHTML`

Comment: @Pytth , maybe because the provided minimal version makes that possible, but the "a,b,c" you see above is to be generated from an API externally, thank you

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Ok I'll try that , I'll be back to you

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Ok I tried it but it's not working, the buttons are not even appearing, I edited the code above so you can see the modification I made

Comment: When you de `myList = [...newList];` - You don't save `myList` to the `$scope` so I wonder how they appear at all

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  I changed the `var myList = []` to `$scope.myList = []` but that didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @John Please check this starter project, it's working for me https://jsfiddle.net/tawq9k78/

Comment: @AlonEitan Good work ! I think the secret was that `ng-bind` directive, but I tried a completely different solution by using the `$compile` service and it works as expected, thank you very much